# HTML.EditorFor not allowing user defined attribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, textbox, compiler-errors

I am trying to implement auto complete textbox using MVC 4 Razor View. so i need to include include on attribute(`data-otf-autocomplete`) to the `HTML.EditorFor` control but it is showing error not allowing to add new attribute ?

Showing Error at :

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Subjects.Name, new { @data-otf-autocomplete="@Url.Action('Autocomplete_Subject')" });
```

**Note:** I can not edit/ change attribute name because that attribute is generated by 3rd party which was included in DLL component.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVC has a convention for working around this, simply use underscores instead of dashes and it will get converted back to dashes as MVC serves the page:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Subjects.Name, new { data_otf_autocomplete = Url.Action("Autocomplete_Subject") })
```

Comment: Adrian Thompson Phillips, `data-otf-autocomplete` was jquery UI plugin and it is included in DLL, I can't modify the attribute name, please let me know is there any alternate way to use dashes in MVC controls ?

Comment: That's no problem, see my answer above, although you've used underscores '_', when you look at the HTML it outputs, it'll render as `data-oft-autocomplete` and should work fine with your jQuery UI plugin.

Answer (score 1):

As per Adrian Thompson Phillips suggestions I have used and Underscores instead of dashes.
`@Html.EditorFor` was not suggest for Autocomplete Text, so I used `@Html.TextBoxFor` instead of `@Html.EditorFor`.

It Works for me!

1. Use Underscores instead of Dashes
2. Use `@Html.TextBoxFor` instead of `@Html.EditorFor`

   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Subjects.Name, new { @data_otf_autocomplete = @Url.Action("Autocomplete_Subject") });